# how to disable type checking or print more debug info while building node project

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, vue.js, webpack

I have a node js project based on vue framework. While building the project using vue-cli-service , the typechecker hangs or stuck at below line..

```
Starting type checking service...
Using 1 worker with 2048MB memory limit
40% building 220/229 modules 9 active usr\abc\node_modules\querystring-   es3\encode.js

40% building 152/164 modules 12 active ..\node_modules\@vue\babel-preset-app\node_modules\core-js\internals\call-with-safe-iteration-closing.js
```

The above line doesn't help me to figure out whats the issue with type checking..

with little bit of research i found out vue-cli uses `fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin`

Is there a way to disable it or print more debug info ?

update: I used below config to not to load it but it still stops there.

```
      // in vue.config.js
  const ForkTsCheckerWebpackPlugin = require('fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin');

  module.exports = {
    configureWebpack: config => {
      // remove the existing ForkTsCheckerWebpackPlugin
      config.plugins = config.plugins.filter(
        p => !(p instanceof ForkTsCheckerWebpackPlugin),
      );
    },
  };
```

Update:

Below are plugins part of vue inspect:

```
        [
          'vue-loader',
          'define',
          'case-sensitive-paths',
          'friendly-errors',
          'html',
          'pwa',
          'preload',
          'prefetch',
          'copy',
          'fork-ts-checker'
        ]
```